# Confusion on calculating a particular derivative when using Cauchy Riemann equations.

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I am given the following (seemingly straight forward problem):

If $f(z)$ and $f(\bar{z})$ are holomorphic functions, show that $f(z)$ is necessarily a constant function.

I know I should use the Cauchy Riemann equation to show that the derivatives of the the functions are are all equal to zero and hence $f$ is a constant. However, I am running into some confusion when calculating the derivatives.

If $f(z) = u(x,y) + iv(x,y)$ then $f(\bar{z}) = u(x,-y) + iv(x,-y)$. The solution to this exercise states that by the CR equations, $$\frac{\partial }{\partial x}u(x,y) = \frac{\partial }{\partial x}u(x,- y) = \frac{\partial }{\partial y}v(x,-y) = -\frac{\partial }{\partial y}v(x,y) = -\frac{\partial }{\partial x}u(x,y) $$

and therefore $\frac{\partial }{\partial x}u(x,y) =0$ (similar argument for other derivatives).

I understand the second equality and the last equality but I am unsure about the first and the third. In general isn't the first equality false since negating the second argument of the function would necessarily change the derivative with respect to $x$. For similar reasons I am unsure of the third inequality.

Here is my attempt at trying to justify $\frac{\partial }{\partial y}v(x,-y) = -\frac{\partial }{\partial y}v(x,y)$ using the chain rule.

We have that $\frac{\partial }{\partial y}v(x,-y) = \frac{\partial }{\partial (-y)}v(x,-y)\frac{\partial }{\partial y}(-y) = - \frac{\partial }{\partial (-y)}v(x,-y)$ But I am unsure where to go from here. I am sure I am completely misunderstanding something trivial but for some reason I can't untie this mental knot I'm having right now.

Comment: I think you may have left your last paragraph unfinished.

Comment: How about substitutions? Put $w-->-y$ in $\frac{\partial }{\partial y}v(x,-y)$ to get $\frac{\partial }{\partial (-w)}v(x,w) = - \frac{\partial }{\partial w}v(x,w)$ (equality  via a chain rule) and then substitute $y --> w$ to get $ = -\frac{\partial }{\partial y}v(x,y)$?